# Перечисления в перечислении!

Tags: массивы, swift, generics, enum

У меня есть `Enum`, который содержит в себе другие enum:

```
   enum Products {
      enum A {
       case bla
       case blabla

      static var name = {
       return "It's product A"
      }

     }

    enum B {
      case mnym
      case mnymmnym

     static var name = {
      return "It's product B"
     }
    }

    let allProductsType: [Any] = [A.self, B.self]
  }
```

Я хочу написать какую-то функцию, которая может проитерироваться по массиву `allProductsType` и вернуть мне элемент, к которому я смог бы обратиться: `element.name.` Возможно ли такое сделать? И если да, то как?

Comment: В итоге я сделал, функцию, которая принимает дженерик тип, итерируется по массиву типов, и возращает мне определенное свойство. Это работает, но чет мне не особо нравится. Как-то это не особо чисто. В итоге чтобы получить какое-то свойство этого типа, мне нужно создавать разные функции, которые будут возвращать то, что мне надо. Но это работает

Comment: Не совсем понятна цель сего. Из того что представил, оптимально - протокол.